# how do I restore to a previous version wherein the .env file is available

Tags: laravel, git

Just a dumb question from just a newb in git, Messed up alot with git, but now I was wondering if how can I restore to a previous version in the application, since my `.env` environment configuration file is now gone in my current master branch, I did merge my other branch with this one. I knew I made my latest work on my `chat-feature` branch, pretty much the 100% of the application was there, since the chat part and the payment feature of the application was there but when I checkout there, its not even working, I was wondering how can I go back to that previous commit that I made. When I git log I want to be back to this specific version.

[image]

Comment: `restore` or `reset`?

Comment: `reset`, sorry: `git reset --hard <commit-number>` should work

Answer (score 0):

## Restore + `push --force`

I don't like to recommend anything that requires `--force` but in your case it may be the cleanest solution. If you shared your code with others, don't follow this - you're changing history.

Let's make `master` be like `chat-feature`.

1. Make a copy of the repo (on your drive), just in case.
2. `git checkout master`
3. `git checkout -b master_copy` (optional, but let's store what we currently have in master as a new branch; this will make it easy to use it if rewind too much)
4. `git checkout chat-feature`
5. Check that this is what you want `master` to look like.
6. `git log -n 1`
7. Copy the commit id
8. `git checkout master`
9. `git reset --hard <commit-id>`
10. Double check that things work and that's what you want.
11. `git push --force`

Comment: Thanks mate, but I think I wasn't paying attention to the right directory of the project, my project's on the `app-latest`, but I was on the `app-repo` directory, dang it, I'll getback to your answer once I'm done..

Comment: I lost my `.env` file here.. What should I do now??

Comment: I don't know what the `.env` file is :(

Comment: it's like an environment configuration file, in laravel, usually it should be added in .gitignore