# VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x000005af] The paging file is too small for this operation to complete when trying to issue an artisan command

Tags: laravel, git

To be honest, I'm completely not proficient with git,

I would appreciate and thank you for the time if you're going to help me
Everytime I issue an artisan command, It won't issue, what could be the possible answer

this command

```
$ php artisan config:cache
VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x000005af] The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
```

These are related to this problems that I also had,

[how do I restore to a previous version wherein the .env file is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775722/how-do-i-restore-to-a-previous-version-wherein-the-env-file-is-available?noredirect=1#comment103846734_58775722)

[How do I recover a .env file that was gone after I commited a .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779089/how-do-i-recover-a-env-file-that-was-gone-after-i-commited-a-gitignore?noredirect=1#comment103845937_58779089)

But, I was able to find a way to recover to those different versions

Comment: What's the output of `php artisan --version` ?

Comment: Also.. if you just made a mistake in a git commit, you have options there as well. [Here is a good read](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/undo-last-commit) with some helpful commands, or of course you can brush up [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert) as well.

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane, it's not even displaying results, it's stucks for like 10 minutes, I mean it's the slowest command in the world...

Comment: I've already edited the memory_limit=-1 so I'd have no memory limit in my project..

Comment: $ php artisan config:cache

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x000005af] The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.